# How to use `bootstrap-datetimepicker` in Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-datetimepicker, laravel-mix, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a Laravel 5.6 bases project. I am trying to use [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix) to compile all my `js/css` resources.

I want to use a javascript datetime-picker that allows me to create a datetime-picke and a range picker on my page. Since I am using css-bootstrap framework for styling, I want to use [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/). I am having hard time trying to install this project using my Mixer setup.

Here is the code that is inside of my `webpack.mix.js` file,

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .scripts([
            'bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/tempusdominus-core.min.js'
        ], 'public/js/app_addons.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

In the `resources/assets/js/app.js` file, I added the following code

```
window.datetimepicker = require('../../../bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/tempusdominus-core.min.js');
```

But in the browser's console, I am getting the following error

> TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

How can I correctly include the [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) in my laravel-mix?

Comment: maybe just add this line in `app.js` : `require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');` i'm not sure about the path here, but just require it without assigning it to variable or something

Comment: of course after you require jquery

Comment: @Hussein I get compiling error when I do that. `Can't resolve....` the following `window.datetimepicker = require('../../../bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/tempusdominus-core.min.js');` does not cause an error but it does not add the datetimepicker to my project

Comment: Install it through npm. [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-datepicker).

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work:

1. remove the reference about `datetime-picker` in `webpack.mix.js`:

   ```
   const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

   mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
   ```
2. copy the file `bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/tempusdominus-core.min.js` to `resources/assets/js/tempusdominus-core.js`
3. add this to `app.js`:

   ```
   window.jQuery = window.$ = $ = require('jquery');
   window.datetimepicker= require('./tempusdominus-core')($);
   //or require('./tempusdominus-core');
   ```

and hopefully will work

Comment: I ended up using the previous version of the package and added this `window.datetimepicker = require('../../../bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js');` which solved the problem

Comment: great then, happy coding :)